# How to check a prop to output a block of code on a styled object in Emotion

Tags: emotion-js

What is the best practice to output a block of code on a [styled object in Emotion](https://emotion.sh/docs/styled#object-styles)?

A simple boolean statement looks like this:

```
const StyledComponent = styled('div')(({ check }) => ({
    position: check ? 'relative' : undefined
})
```

But what is the best solution for a block of code like the following example if I don't want to check each line of code?

```
const StyledComponent = styled('div')(({ check }) => ({
  // some style here
  // ...

  // only load pseud element if "check" is true
  '&::before': {
    content: `''`,
    position: 'absolute',
    left: '0%',
    top: '0%',
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    background: 'blue'
  }
}))
```

I have some solutions in mind.

- Add the if statement on the `content:` as without content the rest won't show. It is not my favourite because the rest of the code still getting loaded.
- Add the if statement to load a new div inside this component. This way I can target this specific div instead of using the pseudo-class `before`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave it some thought and got to this solution:

```
const StyledComponent = styled('div')(
  {
    // some style here
    position: 'relative'
  },
  
  ({ check }) =>
    // only load pseudo element if "check" is true
    check
      ? {
          '&::before': {
            content: `''`,
            position: 'absolute',
            left: '0%',
            top: '0%',
            width: '100%',
            height: '100%'
          }
        }
      : undefined
)
```